# Creating a new "Website Project" in VS2017 Community

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2017

"File > New > Web site" is missing so I am unable to follow a tutorial I intended to use.

"File > New > Project" Is there but I need Web Site.

Visual Studio Community 2017 Version: 15.5.1
ASP.NET is checked in the installer

[image]

I am new to Visual Studio 2017 & any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Update: This is a picture from MSDN showing Web Site is a tab we should have...

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Please check this blog: [Visual Studio 2017 Version 15.5 Preview](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2017/10/11/visual-studio-2017-version-15-5-preview/) and check the following information:

Creating ASP.NET Web Applications: We’ve rearranged the ASP.NET project creation menu items a little bit to improve discoverability and increase the likelihood that you’ll choose the right project type for what you’re trying to do. **Now, the commands to create a Web Applications or a Web Site are visually next to each other in the File->New Project dialog.** This should help the majority of people discover the Create a New Web Application path correctly the first time.

Per the above message, we can know that the File>New-Web Site… has been moved into the File>New>Projects…, I checked it in my VS 2017 15.5.2 and it display as expected, please check the following:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

These is no option anymore in VS to create web site, not creating project.

But you can open existing web site: File -> Open -> Web Site.

To create new web site as project:
File -> New -> Project -> Visual c# -> Web > Web Site:

[image]

Comment: Is that the same as File > New > Web Site ?

Comment: no, this option isn't available anymore, added explanation

Answer (score 1):

Open Visual Studio Installer and select ASP.NET and web development then press modify.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that the initial installation of VS2017 does not include web site projects.  Go the the `File > New > Project` screen and select the option to install more templates.